# Overriding render of RadioSelect in django forms gives unexpected results

Tags: django, forms, radio-button, widget

I want to override the render for RadioSelect in django. (I have done a similar thing for checkboxes and I want both to look the same). The general workflow for this would be to write a custom renderer, and then change the render in the ChoiceInput, BUT when I copy the existing code and run it the html output is not safe and the escaped html string is shown. This is not making any sense as I didn't do any changes to the class yet, other than change the name:

In my widgets.py:

```
class ButtonRadioFieldRenderer(ChoiceFieldRenderer):
    choice_input_class = OtherRadioChoiceInput


class OtherRadioChoiceInput(OtherChoiceInput):
    input_type = 'radio'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OtherRadioChoiceInput, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.value = force_text(self.value)


@html_safe
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class OtherChoiceInput(SubWidget):
    """
    An object used by ChoiceFieldRenderer that represents a single
    <input type='$input_type'>.
    """
    input_type = None  # Subclasses must define this

    def __init__(self, name, value, attrs, choice, index):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.attrs = attrs
        self.choice_value = force_text(choice[0])
        self.choice_label = force_text(choice[1])
        self.index = index
        if 'id' in self.attrs:
            self.attrs['id'] += "_%d" % self.index

    def __str__(self):
        return self.render()

    def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if self.id_for_label:
            label_for = format_html(' for="{}"', self.id_for_label)
        else:
            label_for = ''
        attrs = dict(self.attrs, **attrs) if attrs else self.attrs
        return format_html(
            '<label{}>{} {}</label>', label_for, self.tag(attrs), self.choice_label
        )

    def is_checked(self):
        return self.value == self.choice_value

    def tag(self, attrs=None):
        attrs = attrs or self.attrs
        final_attrs = dict(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=self.name, value=self.choice_value)
        if self.is_checked():
            final_attrs['checked'] = 'checked'
        return format_html('<input{} />', flatatt(final_attrs))

    @property
    def id_for_label(self):
        return self.attrs.get('id', '')
```

In my forms.py:

```
DELIMITER_CHOICES = [
    ('space', ugettext_lazy("space")),
    ('underscore', "_"),
    ]

class SingleDelimiterForm(forms.Form):

    delimiter = forms.ChoiceField(initial=0, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=ButtonRadioFieldRenderer), choices=DELIMITER_CHOICES)
```

The only changes I did was to put "Other" and "Button" in front of already existing classes, and the code doesn't run anymore. If I change OtherChoiceInput to ChoiceInput the code is working. (in the end I only want to add a class to the label...)

Comment: I'm running Django 1.8, this is the plain code from django 1.8 only with name modifications to classes.

Answer (score 0):

I needed unicode strings for the code to work, so `from __future__ import unicode_literals` fixed the issue. I still found this error very confusing.